# Flask - WTForm Select2 implementation for capturing results selected from AJAX

Tags: python, flask, jquery-select2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

My question is pretty straight forward,

I have a working Select2 Ajax implementetion rendering in my HTML, how do I capture the result in a WTForm?

Here is my HTML, and my question revolves around how to add the WTForm tags in the select2 html class so I can capture the result.

```
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                                <label for="exampleInputIconRight">Search Name</label>
                                    <select class="form"></select>
```

Here is my back end in python

```
from app.forms import ( NameForm )

@route('/form-page.html', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def form_page():
    form=NameForm(request.form)
    
    form.name.data = None
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.form['name']
```

forms.py

```
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = TextField()
```

My main doubt is the following, if I was using a normal WTForms
I would simply call the object I passed in the backend and retrieve
the data inputed.

In the html I would have to write something like this:

```
{{ form.name(class="form-control")}}
```

Its just the implementation on the HTML I am not sure about...
Where should I add the tag ? Something like this?

```
                <form method="POST">
                    <div class="row mb-5">
                                <label {{ form.name }} for="exampleInputIconRight">Search Name</label>
                                    <select class="form"></select>
```

I am really not sure how to proceed in order for my form to receive the data from the Select2.

Comment: Where is or what your WTForm tag looks like?

Comment: I have edited my question perhaps I can help you @Tobin

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `wtform` with `Select2` you must first make sure that your `form` uses a field of type `SelectField`

```
from wtforms import SelectField,
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = SelectField()
```

And in your html code you normally render your form by adding a class that you will use as a js selector for your `Select2`

```
<form action='' method="POST">
    <div class="row mb-5">
        {{ form.name(class_="js-select") }}
    </div>
</form>
```

And your `Select2` code:

```
$('.js-select').select2({
    ...
})
```